# Sitecore 7.2 links to csv download in the browser

Tags: c#, csv, sitecore

I want to export Sitecore redirect links to a CSV file. Created in the ribbon a button, and the code referend page in the project.(see below)

```
public class ExportRedirectsListCmd : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var RedirectFolder = new SitecoreContext(GetContentDatabase()).GetItem<BaseCommon>(context.Items[0].ID.ToGuid(), context.Items[0].Language);
        var lstLinkToRedirect = RedirectFolder.Children.OfType<LinkToLinkRedirect>();
        var filename = "RedirectsOutput_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"{"Redirecttype"},{"Sourcelink Url"}, {"Targetlink Url"}");
        // collect all information 
        var allLines = (from item in lstLinkToRedirect
                        select new object[]
                        {
                            item.RedirectType,
                            item.SourceLink.Url,
                            item.TargetLink.Url
                        }).ToList();

        // insert the content
        allLines.ForEach(line =>
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
        });

        // Alertbox just for test
        // SheerResponse.Alert(sb.ToString());
        // return;    
    }
}
```

Code collects all information in the `StringBuilder`. By testing the alert box displays the expected information.

Now to download the `StringBuilder` information to the browser. HttpContext does not work in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file in temp folder then use **SheerResponse.Download()**  API to download the CSV file, I have not tested this, but this is probably what you need :

```
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var RedirectFolder = new SitecoreContext(GetContentDatabase()).GetItem<BaseCommon>(context.Items[0].ID.ToGuid(), context.Items[0].Language);
        var lstLinkToRedirect = RedirectFolder.Children.OfType<LinkToLinkRedirect>();
        var filename = "RedirectsOutput_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"{"Redirecttype"},{"Sourcelink Url"}, {"Targetlink Url"}");
        // collect all information 
        var allLines = (from item in lstLinkToRedirect
                        select new object[]
                        {
                                           item.RedirectType,
                                           item.SourceLink.Url,
                                           item.TargetLink.Url
                        }).ToList();

        // insert the content
        allLines.ForEach(line =>
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
        });
        string filePath = "/temp/" + filename;
        using( TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
       {
           tw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
           tw.Close();
       }
       SheerResponse.Download(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It didn't work for me, but the solution for it was found by a colleague. I put it on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/links-to-csv-download-in-the-browser/8515#8515